# Value repeated while XML to Dataframe parsing

Tags: python, xml, csv, elementtree

The purpose of the code is to take elements from xml files and parse them into a csv file.

Lately I have updated the code so the codes goes to **Phones** (another child of ProjectData) takes elements from **Set** and **Get** attaches them together with underscore and parses them into the first column with the header name **Identify**
This is my code

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path
import csv
from pathlib import Path


directory = 'C:/Users/TRY/try.xml'

with open('try.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
   #◙ writer = csv.writer(f)

    headers = ['identify','id', 'service_code', 'rational', 'qualify', 'description_num', 'description_txt','Counter', 'set_data_xin', 'set_data_xax', 'set_data_value', 'set_data_x']

    writer.writerow(headers)

    xml_files_list = list(map(str,Path(directory).glob('**/*.xml')))
    for xml_file in xml_files_list:
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        p_get = tree.find('.//Phones/Get').text
        p_set = tree.find('.//Phones/Set').text


        start_nodes = root.findall('.//START')
        for sn in start_nodes:
            row = defaultdict(str)

            # <<<<< Indentation was wrong here
            for k,v in sn.attrib.items():
                row[k] = v
            for rn in sn.findall('.//Rational'):
                row['Rational'] = rn.text

            for qu in sn.findall('.//Qualify'):
                row['Qualify'] = qu.text

            for ds in sn.findall('.//Description'):
                row['Description_txt'] = ds.text
                row['Description_text_id'] = ds.attrib['text_id']



            for counter, st in enumerate( sn.findall('.//SetData') ):
                for k,v in st.attrib.items():
                    if v.startswith("-"):
                        v = v.replace("-","",1)
                    v=v.replace(',', '.')
                    row['SetData_'+ str(k)] = v
                row["Counter"] = counter 
                row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]
                row_data[0]=p_get + '_' + p_set
                writer.writerow(row_data)
                row = defaultdict(str)
```

This is the xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectData>
 <Phones>
    <Date />
    <Prog />
    <Box />
    <Feature />
    <IN>MAFWDS</IN>
    <Set>234234</Set>
    <Pr>23423</Pr>
    <Number>afasfhrtv</Number>
    <Simple>dfasd</Simple>
    <Nr />
    <Get>6070106091</Get>
    <Reno>1233</Reno>
  </Phones>
<FINAL>
    <START id="B001" service_code="0x5196">
      <Docs Docs_type="START">
        <Rational>225196</Rational>
        <Qualify>6251960000A0DE</Qualify>
      </Docs>
      <Description num="1213f2312">The parameter</Description>
      <DataFile dg="12" dg_id="let">
        <SetData value="32" />
      </DataFile>
    </START>
    <START id="C003" service_code="0x517B">
      <Docs Docs_type="START">
        <Rational>23423</Rational>
        <Qualify>342342</Qualify>
      </Docs>
      <Description num="3423423f3423">The third</Description>
      <DataFile dg="55" dg_id="big">
        <SetData x="E1" value="21259" />
        <SetData x="E2" value="02" />
      </DataFile>
    </START>
    <START id="Z048" service_code="0x5198">
      <RawData rawdata_type="ASDS">
        <Rational>225198</Rational>
        <Qualify>3432433</Qualify>
      </RawData>
      <Description num="434234234">The forth</Description>
      <DataFile unit="21" unit_id="FEDS">
        <FileX unit="eg" discrete="false" axis_pts="19" name="Vsome" text_id="bx5" unit_id="GDFSD" />
        <SetData xin="5" xax="233" value="323" />
        <SetData xin="123" xax="77" value="555" />
        <SetData xin="17" xax="65" value="23" />
      </DataFile>
    </START>
</FINAL>
</ProjectData>
```

The output looks like this and how it should look like.

[image]

The problem is that the column **identify** is being repeated. I want so it doesn’t repeat.
I have tried to play with the code and move this variable around the code but no success, finding it hard to solve this problem since column is composed from elements of another child of the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets `row_data[0]` per each row_data which is written to the csv file, and because of that it is repeated on each line in the csv file.

If you want to only see it once per original row, you must set it directly in `row` before the inner loop `for counter, st in enumerate( sn.findall('.//SetData') ):`

For example:

```
        row['identify']=p_get + '_' + p_set
        for counter, st in enumerate( sn.findall('.//SetData') ):
            for k,v in st.attrib.items():
                if v.startswith("-"):
                    v = v.replace("-","",1)
                v=v.replace(',', '.')
                row['SetData_'+ str(k)] = v
            row["Counter"] = counter 
            row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]
            writer.writerow(row_data)
            row = defaultdict(str)
```